# C string array sizeof() changes

Tags: c, string

```
void func(char *s[]){
    printf("s: %d\n", sizeof(s));
}

void caller(){
    char *a[2];
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        a[i] = (char *)malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
    }
    strcpy(a[0], "something");
    strcpy(a[1], "somethingelse");

    printf("a: %d\n", sizeof(a));

    func(a);
}
```

This outputs

```
a: 16
s: 8
```

Why is the output of `sizeof()` different in `caller()` and `func()`? Also, is it possible for `func` to get the number of `char *` in the array via `sizeof`?

Comment: Welcome to strings/arrays in C. It's decaying to a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

One is an array of two character pointers.  The other is a pointer to an array of pointers.  They're not the same size.

Comment: Was it really necessary to answer this instead of voting to close? This has been answered many times before, and should be closed.

Comment: I wanted to try to answer it. I'm not interested in checking to see if a question has been answered before I try to answer it. I'm here to learn by testing my understanding. If that's annoying to you, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++,[Array decays into a pointer](http://web.archive.org/web/20081208122434/http://www.transcendentaxis.com/dthompson/blog/archives/9).char *s[] is a pointer, the size of pointer is always fixed 4 or 8 (depends upon machine).

Comment: Actually, no. It's decaying to a pointer in this scenario.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII  :Exactly decaying pointers.I forgot the exact name.I Updated my answer. Thanks!